# The command is not kicking the member

Tags: command, discord.py

I added a kick command with none reason for kicks but the bot cannot kick a member, but the permissions are working well.
what is the problem with this code?

```py
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has been kick')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use cogs change `@client.command()` to `@commands.command()` or delete `self` argument.

I recommend read:

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html
https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be

Answer (score -2):

```
await member.kick(reason=reason)
```

Change this line to

```
await client.kick(member)
```

Comment: Still not working and error is

discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: @MoseRattoe, there's nothing wrong with your code, it's mostly a permission issue. `client.kick(member)` is for `discord.py` v1.0. You are not using that version.